# Kivy - How to access kivy widget in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to edit a text in a TextInput in kivy but don't know how to, I've tried this code as Ive search in the net but still no luck.

```
class MainApp(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass

class Forms(BoxLayout): 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.txtSearch.text = "new text"

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()

------kivy-------

<Main>:
    TextInput:
        id: txtSearch
```

this is not my whole code but I think those are what matters in the issue

this is the error:

```
    File "C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Python\Kivy\Project\main.py", line 295, in <module>
 ''')
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1828, in load_string
 self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1985, in _apply_rule
 self.apply(child)
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1872, in apply
 self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1986, in _apply_rule
 self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1986, in _apply_rule
 self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
 File "D:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\kivy34\kivy\lang.py", line 1983, in _apply_rule
 child = cls(__no_builder=True)
 File "C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Python\Kivy\Project\main.py", line 40, in __init__
 self.ids.txtSearch.text = "new text"
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 720, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (kivy\properties.c:10911)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Comment: oops a mistype, thats Forms class

Comment: So the `kv` file should be changed accordingly: `<Forms>:`... Although you probably want `Forms:`, to actually instantiate a widget.

Comment: You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you post a [mcve].

Comment: There are several problems with your code, including that `Main` is not a widget, `root_widget` is not defined in your build method, and you call `super(Main, ...)` in the `__init__` of `Forms`.

Answer (score 2):

To change Widgets properties in kivy you need to 'link' the widget between .py and .kv file, first in .py file:

```
txt_Search = ObjectProperty()
```

then in .kv file, in your root widget:

```
txt_Search: txtSearch
```

then assign the id to a widget (as you already did):

```
<Main>:
    TextInput:
        id: txtSearch
        text: ' '
```

then in your .py file, you can change attributes of the widget by doing this:

```
self.txt_Search.text = 'New Text'
```

or any other attribute:

```
self.txt_Search.height = '30dp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `self.ids.txtSearch` exists when you try to assign a `text` to it? You're calling `super(Main,self)` one line above so I guess `txtSearch` is never instantiated.

Btw, it's better to init widgets in `*.kv` files:

```
<Main>:
    TextInput:
        id: txtSearch
        text: "new text"
```